# Indent paragraphs

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I wrote all my text using the command `\paragraph{}` and now I'm difficulties to indent and set the spacing between paragraphs. I would like to indent the first line of paragraphs with spacing of 1.25 cm. But when I use `\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}` the first line don't set. Is there any way to set the first line of the paragraph using the command ? And how can I set the distance between the paragraphs to `0cm`, created with `\paragraph` ?

ex:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{} \lipsum[1] %tow spaces between paragraph

\paragraph{} \lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3] %anyone spaces between paragraph
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\paragraph` is a sectioning command like `\section`: it does not mean 'start a new paragraph'. If that is what you mean here, you should be leaving a blank line between the paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you man, I really did not know that. So what's the real utility of the command `\paragraph{}`? when I can use it ?

Comment: `\paragraph{<text>}` is a "lower" type of heading (in the sense that `\chapter{<text>}` is "higher" than `\section{<text>}`, which is higher than `\subsection{<text>}`).

Comment: To change the vertical distance between paragraphs, don't modify `\parindent`. Instead, do something like `\addtolength\parskip{1\baselineskip}`.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge and thx for your help =)

Comment: @Freitas `\paragraph` is just what could have been called `\subsubsubsection` except that that name is getting long. If you set `tocdepth` and `secnumdepth` counters higher than 4 you will see it produces numbered headings and table of contents entries assuming that it is just below subsubsection in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually chose a poor example, since `\lipsum` starts a new paragraph unless you call the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) with the `nopar` option. As such, leaving an empty space between paragraphs is fine to separate paragraphs.

Issuing a `\paragraph{}` to start a new paragraph is, however, not the best idea. You can "rectify" this by redefining what `\paragraph` means. In this case, it suffices to make it equivalent to `\ignorespaces`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\let\paragraph\ignorespaces
\begin{document}
\paragraph{} \lipsum[1]

\paragraph{} \lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change your document, deleting all `\paragraph` commands, you can load the `titlesec` package and issue

```
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0cm}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{0pt}{0cm}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{}\lipsum[1] %tow spaces between paragraph

\paragraph{} \lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3] %anyone spaces between paragraph
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Para sangrar escribe, y toma en cuenta que `0.25cm = 1` espacio.
`\parindent=1.25cm`

y para el espaciado entre parráfos escribe y toma en cuenta que el `1.5` es a espacio y medio.

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This site uses English, could you please translate your answer?